# MySQL -- Join data query from multiple Tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to query from "T_Tester (table 1#)" but some data come from "T_handler (table 2#)".
I tried 'inner join' but not working.

My code is here, I am pretty sure something went wrong...

```
     select * from T_Tester
     inner join T_handler where T_handler.Tester=T_Tester.Tester;
```

Table example:

```
    ========================
    T_Tester (table 1#)
    ========================
    Tester      Data
    Tester-001  qqq
    Tester-001  www
    Tester-001  eee
    Tester-001  rrrr
    Tester-001  ttt
    Tester-001  yyyy

    ========================
    T_handler (table 2#)
    ========================
     Tester     Handler
     Tester-001 Handler-006
     Tester-002 Handler-005
     Tester-003 Handler-004
     Tester-004 Handler-003
     Tester-005 Handler-002
     Tester-006 Handler-001
```

**Need Help:**

Output I want. 
Combining 2 tables with this sequence : 'T_Tester.Tester','T_handler.Handler','T_Tester.Data'.

```
    ========================
    Query output 
    ========================
     Tester     Handler     Data
     Tester-001 Handler-006 qqq
     Tester-001 Handler-006 www
     Tester-001 Handler-006 eee
     Tester-001 Handler-006 rrrr
     Tester-001 Handler-006 ttt
     Tester-001 Handler-006 yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a `left outer join`.

```
select distinct 
    T.Tester, 
    H.Handler, 
    D.Data 
from 
    T_Tester T
        left outer join T_handler H 
            on H.Tester = T.Tester
```

Comment: left outer join not working with 'where'? failed to execute. Then when I change 'where' to 'on', the 'Handler' returned null. any idea?

Comment: Change "where" to "on"

Comment: Good self-reminder to not answer questions at end of a long day ;)

Comment: 'left outer join' shows only left Table data only ( T.tester). I changed to 'right outer join' (Handler, Data). then it shows right table data only. how to make it to show both table?

Comment: Hmmm... sounds like it's not joining. Does each table contain same data type for Tester field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join:-

```
select T.Tester, H.Handler, T.Data from T_Tester T inner join T_handler H where T.Tester=H.Tester;
```

Refer this:-
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Tester,t1.Handler,t2.Data from T_handler t1 inner join T_Tester t2 where t1.Tester = t2.Tester;
```